# Can't use a typed DataRowView in my DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism

We just started a WPF project using Prism. Our problem is that we have to use System.Data.DataRowView instead of our typed versions for the DataGrid.
We are using the code like this:

```
<DataGrid 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}" 
                    SelectedItem="{Binding ActiveCar}" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
<!--[...]-->
<CheckBox Content="Four-wheel drive" IsChecked="{Binding TypedActiveCar.FourWheelDrive}"/>


<!--[...]-->

    private System.Data.DataRowView _activeCar;

    public System.Data.DataRowView ActiveCar
    {
        get { return _activeCar; }
        set
        {
            if (_activeCar!= value)
            {

                _activeCar= value;
                var fCarRow =
                    (_activeCar.Row as CarDS.F_CarRow);

                RaisePropertyChanged(() => ActiveCar);
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => TypedActiveCar);
            }
        }
    }

    public CarDS.F_CarRow TypedActiveCar
    {
        get
        {
            if (ActiveCar != null)
            {
                return ActiveCar.Row as CarDS.F_CarRow;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public CarDS.F_CarDataTable Cars
    {
        get { return _data.F_Cars; }

        set
        {
            if (_data.F_Cars != value)
            {

                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Cars);
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => ActiveCar);
            }
        }
    }
```

This implementation is working, but I would prefer using the typed version in the table as my SelectedItem. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Would you post the code for 'Cars' referenced in your ItemsSource binding?

Comment: Sure, i added it in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataRows, DataViews, DataRowViews, and the other System.Data Types are meant for the organization of data and are not internally analgous to any of the DataGrid stuff (except perhaps conceptually). The display of this data is meant for the ease of use for developer's and uses its own architecture, separate from the System.Windows.Controls namespace. You can convert the information from a DataRowView to some kind of DataGridRow, but that's the most you can do.